# Azure monitor Containers and prometheus integration

Tags: prometheus, azure-aks

Trying to use Prometheus for **scraping** metrics for ASP.NET Core webapi deployed as linux docker conatiner in AKS. Here below are few more details about AKS:

1. Using Nginx Ingress internal load balancer with with prometheus metric collection enabled. Able to collect Nigin Ingress metrics with Prometheus and could see metrics in Azure Monitor for containers.
   Added Nginx ingress service url in ConfigMap(container-azm-ms-agentconfig.yaml)
2. For **scraping** application data (ASP.NET core webapi) below steps are fallowed

a. Have used prometheus nuget package and instrumented application. Able to see metrics by http:\localhost:80\metrics

b. Created docker container and able to browse metrics.

c. In dockercompose.yaml file enabled prometheus.io/scrape: "true" annotation and deployed with cluster type service.

d. In ConfigMap enabled  monitor_kubernetes_pods = true and added http://tododocker-one.ingress-basic:80/metrics under kubernates services. Here tododocker-one is cluster type service in ingress-basic namespace.

No errors are found in omsagent logs. With all these steps could not see application metrics in Azure monitor neither able to get output for

http://tododocker-one.ingress-basic:80/metrics.

What could be the issue. I am using Nginx ingess internal load balancer with routing rules does that have any impact.

Comment: hello could you share the following
1) container-azm-ms-agentconfig.yaml
2) your ingress manifest
3) your pod's service manifest

Also is your application exposing prometheus metrics @ /metrics ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that your pod exposes a metric path (e.g. /metrics) and that your pod's service allows prometheus from accessing this endpoint through the k8s  service.

From your error above, assuming that the four different IPs are pod IPs off your own services, they don't seem to be exposing the /metrics on port 8080 or 9102.

Have a look at this article on how to have your pod/service service prometheus metrics through an endpoint.

https://sysdig.com/blog/kubernetes-monitoring-prometheus/#monitoringkubernetesclusterwithprometheusandkubestatemetrics

also, make sure you configure `container-azm-ms-agentconfig.yaml` properly with the right service endpoint's port and path (in cause you are not exposing the metrics on a /metrics but something else)

have a look at those settings

https://github.com/microsoft/OMS-docker/blob/ci_feature_prod/Kubernetes/container-azm-ms-agentconfig.yaml#L65-L71

Comment: yes able to integrate Prometheus in AKS. Have enabled Ingress with Prometheus and able to pull Ingress metrics. Still need to instrument application with Prometheus and build Grafana dashoard.